# Visual studio 2022 settings

Tags: visual-studio, settings

I opened visual studio this morning and found all the project windows closed and not as I left them last time. How do you restore it.

Thank you

Comment: You mean the open files? Or the tool windows? Very different issue.

Comment: Tool windows ... IDE VS ... forms, modules, classes, etc

Answer (score 0):

The screen layout may be reset if the corresponding configuration file was corrupted for some reason. You can save your preferred layout in the `Window` menu (`Save Window layout`) and restore it later. This is helpful if this happens again.

There's also a `Reset window layout` menu item, in case things got really messed up (which seems to be the case for you). You can also get all the tool windows back individually by finding them in the `View` menu.